# chef cookbook cannot run sqllocaldb with execute resource

Tags: sql, azure, express, chef-infra

Have been struggling with this cookbook for a while.

I am trying to install a number of resources including the Azure SDK onto a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance.

Initially I received the following error in the stacktrace:

```
Generated at 2014-07-01 14:59:23 +0000
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: windows_package[WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi] 
(azure_sdk::default line 29) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed:  
Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127], but received '1603'
---- Begin output of msiexec /qn /i "c:\chef\chef- 
cache\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of msiexec /qn /i "c:\chef\chef-cache\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi" 
----
```

I added steps to stop, delete, create and start **sqllocaldb**

However, now I am receiving the following error:

```
Generated at 2014-08-02 07:54:19 +0000
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[stop-sqllocaldb] (azure_sdk::default line 
18) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with 
[0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of sqllocaldb stop v11.0 ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 'sqllocaldb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable  
program or batch file.
---- End output of sqllocaldb stop v11.0 ----
```

I suspect there may be some form of timing issue (i.e. sqllocaldb isn't ready) because if I ssh to the server and then re run chef, the the entire cookbook is processed perfectly and all my resources are installed.

Note. I tried using the retries attribute however, I don't believe that **execute** supports this attribute.

I am including the entire recipe below:

```
%w{ SqlLocalDB.msi }.each do |pkg|
  windows_package "#{pkg}" do
    source "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qainstallerfiles/#{pkg}"
  options "IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES /qn"
  installer_type :custom
    action :install
  end
end

%w{ WindowsAzureTools.vs140.exe }.each do |pkg|
  windows_package "#{pkg}" do
    source "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qainstallerfiles/#{pkg}"
    installer_type :nsis
    action :install
  end
end

execute "stop-sqllocaldb" do
 command "sqllocaldb stop v11.0"
    retries 5
    retry_delay 30 
 action :run
end

execute "delete-sqllocaldb" do
 command "sqllocaldb delete v11.0"
    retries 5
    retry_delay 30 
 action :run
end

execute "delete-WAStorageEmulator" do
 command "del C:\Users\Administrator\WAStorageEmulatorDb3*.*"
 action :run
end

execute "create-sqllocaldb" do
 command "sqllocaldb create v11.0"
    retries 5
    retry_delay 30 
 action :run
end

execute "start-sqllocaldb" do
 command "sqllocaldb start v11.0"
    retries 5
    retry_delay 30 
 action :run
end

%w{ WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi }.each do |pkg|
  windows_package "#{pkg}" do
    source "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qainstallerfiles/#{pkg}"
    retries 5
    retry_delay 30
    action :install
  end
end

%w{ WindowsAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi}.each do |pkg|
  windows_package "#{pkg}" do
    source "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qainstallerfiles/#{pkg}"
    action :install
  end
end

%w{ WindowsAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi }.each do |pkg|
  windows_package "#{pkg}" do
    source "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qainstallerfiles/#{pkg}"
    action :install
  end
end

%w{ WindowsAzureEmulator-x64.exe }.each do |pkg|
  windows_package "#{pkg}" do
    source "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qainstallerfiles/#{pkg}"
  options '/quiet /msicl ACCEPTLICENSE=1'
  installer_type :custom
    action :install
  end
end
```

Many thanks for any help that you can give.

Comment: Is the `sqllocaldb` binary in your `$Path`?

Comment: Hi. Yes sqllocaldb is in the path. Eventually. i.e. When I ssh later and try and run the start command in powershell, it runs fine. Furthermore, if I re-run  chef, then the whole cookbook is applied successfully. That's why I wondered about timing. sqllocaldb.msi is the first package applied in the cookbook but it is almost as if the service hasn't gotten around to starting by the time I try to execute sqllocaldb from the command line

Comment: Is sqllocaldb somehow not on your path during the first run? Maybe it is on the path afterwards but not during... what happens if you supply the full path to sqllocaldb.exe in `stop-sqllocaldb`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you modify an environment variable, such as $PATH, it's not updated in any running process, only newly-started ones. Which explains why it works if you re-run it; the new instance of chef-client picks up the new path. The solution is to specify the full path to `sqllocaldb` in the command.